# DynamoDB: can Local Secondary Indexes be sparse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I understand GSI's can be sparse, however the docs don't seem to mention LSI's - can they also be sparse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they can.  While the [sparse indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) document explicitly mentions GSI,  the very first example:

> For example, suppose that you have a table where you store all your
> customer orders, with the following key attributes:
>
> Partition key: CustomerId
>
> Sort key: OrderId
>
> To track open orders, you can insert an attribute named isOpen in
> order items that have not already shipped. Then when the order ships,
> you can delete the attribute. If you then create an index on
> CustomerId (partition key) and isOpen (sort key), only those orders with isOpen defined appear in it.

Is talking about an LSI.  The index partition key is the same as the table itself (`CustomerID`).